# Admin menu link is not removed with Wordpress "register_uninstall_hook"

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins

I'm studying WP plugin development and I'm not able to delete a link from a admin page menu when I uninstall my plugin. This admin page I created in the admin menu through "add_menu_page".
I'll leave here the summarized example of how I'm using it.
MAIN PAGE:

´´´

```
require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'classes/NerdyPluginUninstall.php';

class NerdyPluginFormEvents {

// all the plugin activation code...

// PLUGIN UNINSTALL CODE
public function uninstall(){

    $excluiItemMenuAdmin       = new NerdyPluginUninstall();
    $deleteItemMenuAdmin       = $excluiItemMenuAdmin->mm_uninstall_function();
    $this->deleteItemMenuAdmin = $deleteItemMenuAdmin;
    
}

if ( class_exists('NerdyPluginFormEvents')){
    $plugin_form_events = new NerdyPluginFormEvents();
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array(      
    $plugin_form_events, 'activate') );
    register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array( 
    $plugin_form_events, 'deactivate' ) );
    register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__, array( 
    $plugin_form_events, 'uninstall' ) );
}  // endif 

}
```

´´´

CLASSES/UNINSTALL PAGE:

´´´

```
class NerdyPluginUninstall {

public function __construct() {
    
    add_action( 'admin_menu', [ $this, 'mm_uninstall_function'] );
   
    }

function mm_uninstall_function()
{
   if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    remove_admin_page( 'mm_admin_menu' );
}
}
```

´´´

I only managed to remove the link when installing the plugin, but the intention is to permanently remove this link when uninstalling the plugin.

Thanks if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

In a properly constructed plugin, you call `add_menu_page()` from your code that handles the `admin_menu` hook. Somewhere in your plugin's initialization code you mention that hook and your handler function in a call to `add_action()`. That initialization code runs *on every page view*.

After you deactivate your plugin your initialization code doesn't run any more. So you don't have to do anything extra to remove your menu: it never gets added in the first place.

The convention for plugins is to remove any custom data (option settings for example) they create upon deinstallation, not deactivation. It's usually best to leave your custom data in place upon deactivation so it's still there if your user reactivates your plugin. But you should always remove custom data when the user uninstalls your plugin, otherwise the sites of your former users will contain junk data.

You can use `register_uninstall_hook()` for that.

Comment: Hello...thanks for the reply. The problem still persists. I'll post here a detailed summary of the code.